# Need help understanding why data is being removed from all my lists

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I currently have questions and answers being loaded in from a .json file into unity and then this data is placed inside a unansweredquestions list which then when a new question is generated it removes the current question being displayed. however, it also removes the data main list where the information is loaded in to. The code below is what is used to do this:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.IO;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    
    public class QuestionHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] public Text questionText;
        [SerializeField] public Text answerAText;
        [SerializeField] public Text answerBText;
        [SerializeField] public Text answerCText;
    
        [SerializeField]
        private QuestionData _QuestionData = new QuestionData();
        public static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;
        private Question currentQuestion;
        private QuestionData questionData;
    
        public void SaveIntoJson()
        {
            string question = JsonUtility.ToJson(_QuestionData, true);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json", question);
            Debug.Log(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json");
        }
    
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            if(!Directory.Exists(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData");
                File.Create(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json");
                SaveIntoJson();
            }
            Load();
            Debug.Log(_QuestionData.questions[0].questionName);
    
            //if the unansweredQuestion list has no data or all the questions have been removed it will copy in the data from the _QuestionData list
            if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("No questions present loading in saved data");
                unansweredQuestions = _QuestionData.questions;
            }
            Debug.Log(unansweredQuestions[0].questionName);
    
            SetCurrentQuestion();
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            
        }
        public void SetCurrentQuestion()
        {
            int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
            currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];
    
            questionText.text = currentQuestion.questionName;
            answerAText.text = currentQuestion.answerA;
            answerBText.text = currentQuestion.answerB;
            answerCText.text = currentQuestion.answerC;
        }
    
        public void SetNewCurrentQuestion()
        {
            if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("No more questions left in the list!");
                _QuestionData = questionData;
            }
            else
            {
                //removes current question from the list so no question comes up twice
                unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);
    
                //randomly picks a new question out the remaining questions
                int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
                currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];
    
                questionText.text = currentQuestion.questionName;
                answerAText.text = currentQuestion.answerA;
                answerBText.text = currentQuestion.answerB;
                answerCText.text = currentQuestion.answerC;
    
                Debug.Log(_QuestionData.questions.Count);
                Debug.Log(unansweredQuestions.Count);
            }        
        }
    
        void Load()
        {
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json");
            string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    
            questionData = JsonUtility.FromJson<QuestionData>(data);
            Debug.Log("Got Data!");
            //sets the loaded questiondata into the game question list
            _QuestionData = questionData;
        }
    
        private void OnApplicationQuit()
        {
            //SaveIntoJson();
        }
    }
    
    //format of the questions within the game
    [System.Serializable]
    public class QuestionData
    {
        public List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
    }
    
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Question
    {
        public string questionName;
        public string answerA;
        public bool isA;
        public string answerB;
        public bool isB;
        public string answerC;
        public bool isC;
    }
```

Shows the main unity screen with the question data down the left side:

[image]

Any help understanding this would be great I've tried using `debug.log` to see what's going on but I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
unansweredQuestions = _QuestionData.questions;
```

So after this line both fields point to the same list reference. => When you later remove the question via

```
unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);
```

This item is removed from the `_QuestionData.questions` since it **is the same list**.

---

To avoid that you rather should create and work on **a copy** of the list instead like

```
unansweredQuestions = new List<Question>(_QuestionData.questions);
```

---

Then for the saving you would probably want to only keep the `unansweredQuestions` except for the first time

```
public void SaveIntoJson(bool overwriteWithUnanswered = true)
{
    if(overwriteWithUnanswered) _QuestionData.questions = unansweredQuestions;

    var question = JsonUtility.ToJson(_QuestionData, true);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json", question);
    Debug.Log(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json");
}
```

And pass in `false` only the first time in `Start

```
if(!Directory.Exists(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData");
    File.Create(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/QuestionGameData/QuestionData.json");
    SaveIntoJson(false);
}
```

---

Two further notes:

- In general for filepaths you should always use `Path.Combine` instead of manually concatenate `+ "/"`
- you should store the path **once** instead of all the time getting it again and again

  ```
    private readonly string filePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "QuestionGameData", "QuestionData.json");
  ```

and then simply re-use it everywhere like e.g in

```
public void SaveIntoJson(bool overwriteWithUnanswered = true)
{
    if(overwriteWithUnanswered) _QuestionData.questions = unansweredQuestions;

    var question = JsonUtility.ToJson(_QuestionData, true);
    Debug.Log(filePath);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, questions);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a reference copy. Create a new list

```
        //sets the loaded questiondata into the game question list
        _QuestionData.questions  = new List<Question>(questionData);


List<Question> mainlist = new List<Question>();
    List<Question> sublist = new List<Question>();
    Question current;
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Question
    {
        public string questionName;
        public string answerA;
        public bool isA;
        public string answerB;
        public bool isB;
        public string answerC;
        public bool isC;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Question  {questionName} = Answer {answerA} ";
        }
    }

    public void Load() {
        mainlist = new List<Question>() {
        
            new Question(){questionName="Question A",answerA="A" },
             new Question(){questionName="Question B",answerA="B" },
              new Question(){questionName="Question C",answerA="C" },
               new Question(){questionName="Question D",answerA="D" },

        };

        // sublist = mainlist; if you uncommment these you will get the same behavior you have.
        sublist = new List<Question>(mainlist); ///Do these in order to avoid reference problems
    }
    public void showList(List<Question> sublist)
    {

        foreach (var item in sublist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    public void showList()
    {

        showList(mainlist);
        showList(sublist);
    }
    public void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
        int randomQuestionIndex = new Random().Next(0, mainlist.Count);
        current = mainlist[randomQuestionIndex];

    }
    public void Remove()
    {
        sublist.Remove(current);
    
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Load();
        p.SetCurrentQuestion();
        p.Remove();
        p.showList();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```